# Docker+Nginx allow upstream gunicorn from outside docker

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn

I have a docker-compose container running `Nginx` that I'd like to use with `Flask` + `Gunicorn` running outside of docker on the same machine. When I run both inside Docker everything runs fine via the `docker-compose.yml` `links`, however when I run `Flask` + `Gunicorn` outside of `Docker` I get an error that I want to resolve. How can I fix this error?

The error I get is

```
2020/07/17 03:24:49 [error] 38#38: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: website.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "website.com"
```

I'm running `gunicorn` via `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app`

My nginx `website.conf`

```
upstream hello_server {
    #server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    server 0.0.0.0:5000;
}

    server {
        listen 80;
        # ...

        location ^~ /static/ {
            # Path of your static files
            root /var/www;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://frontends;
        }
    }
}
```

My `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:

  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80/tcp
      - 443:443/tcp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HOST` IP, for example, the upstream is running on port `5000`, all you need to point `frontend` to HOST IP for example `192.168.0.1`.

```
 server {
        listen 80;
        location ^~ /static/ {
            # Path of your static files
            root /var/www;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1:5000;
        }
    }
```

or with upstream variable

```
upstream gunicornapp {
    server 192.168.43.84:3000;
}

    server {
        listen 80;
        location ^~ /static/ {
            # Path of your static files
            root /var/www;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://gunicornapp;
        }
    }
```